# How can I make a checkbox and a label appear on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<li>
   <label for="RememberMe" class="checkbox remember-me">Remember me?</label>

   <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RememberMe">
   <input type="hidden" value="false" name="RememberMe">
</li>
```

CSS for this is as follows:

```
.form label, .form .label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

form input[type="radio"], form input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    padding: 0;
}
```

My problem is that the words "Remember me" appear on one line and the 
checkbox appears below it.

How can I make it so that the checkbox appears to the left of the words "Remember me". Would I need to use float: left or 
make the label not appear as disply: block?

**Update:**

Thanks for all the suggestions. I can't really change the master CSS for my application. Is it possi ble for me to make the changes with some specific CSS for example:

```
label.remember-me {

}

input#RememberMe {

}
```

Comment: For me it was looking fine here http://jsfiddle.net/VBG6B/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display property for label should be `inline-block`. You can read more about display options [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

```
.form label, .form .label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YxWAq/)

Update:

```
.form label.remember-me{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YxWAq/2/)

Comment: I updated my question. Can you have a look and see if this is also something I could do?

Answer (score 2):

you used `Display:Block` in `label` css that is the problem.
remove it and it will be working.

Checkbox on the left.

```
<li>   
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RememberMe"/>
<label for="RememberMe" class="checkbox remember-me">Remember me?</label>
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="RememberMe"/>
</li>
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBG6B/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.form label, .form .label {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

form input[type="radio"], form input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    padding: 0;
}

<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RememberMe">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="RememberMe">
<label for="RememberMe" class="checkbox remember-me">Remember me?</label>
```

Comment: Anurag. Can I just add new CSS that would override?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this : it will display `checkbox` on left side and `remember me?` right side.

```
<form>
    <li>
       <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RememberMe">
       <label for="RememberMe" class="checkbox remember-me">Remember me?</label>
       <input type="hidden" value="false" name="RememberMe">
    </li>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove display:block from form label, and put 'float:left;' on the input checkbox.

And are you using class .label or is that an error,

You can do your update with:

```
  label .remember-me {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
  }

 input[name=RememberMe] {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
   margin-top: 0.5em;
   padding: 0;
   float:left;
   clear:left;
 }
```

You may have to use !important or a parent #id as an additional selector point that's available in the DOM.

Comment: But what do I put in the update that will change it from the default?